# zend and Wamp Configuration

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, wamp, wampserver

I am new to **Zend**. My problem is that I am making a new Controller but unable to access that controller. For example if Controller name is Test I got this error.

`File does not exist: E:/ZendProject/zendy/public/test`

I did lots of searches but can't solve the problem. I change the **httpd.conf** and made this change

`AllowOverride None` to
`AllowOverride All` but than I can't get access to the main page and it says it is forbidden. Here is my **httpd.conf** file snapshot

```
Include "c:/wamp/alias/*"
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "E:\ZendProject\zendy\public"
    ServerName zendy

    <directory "E:\ZendProject\zendy\public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride None
         Options None
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Help me in this regard

Answer (score 1):

as you didn't provide any detailed description about your problem i suggest,

please follow the quickstart application provided by the zend framework , it will solve all your doubts,

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.html

also i suggest to take a look at the best example for beginners on zend by rob Allen,

http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/....

i hope this will help..